# how to add an xml file dynamically multiple times for the same ViewGroup in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an xml file called

> rowitem.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/pic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and I want this layout to be added to every column item in TableLayout

```
for (int raw = 0; raw < 5; raw++) {
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.setOrientation(TableRow.HORIZONTAL);

    // here I want to add the same rowitem.xml about four times in the same row

}
```

I tried to get it with the inflater but it doesnt work

Comment: where is inflater code.can you post it?

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.id.rowItem, null);

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
LayoutInflater vi= (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
tableRow.setOrientation(TableRow.HORIZONTAL);


for (int raw = 0; raw < 5; raw++)
{
  View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.rowItem, null);
  // here I want to add the same rowitem.xml about four times in the same row
  tableRow .addView(v);

}
```

Comment: @Moe as u r adding views horizontally you have to use fixed width of inflate layout otherwise you cannot see the other views.

Comment: ok I will try to move the inflater outside the loop like just said and get back the result...

Comment: @Moe do you want to add 4 views horizontally in 1 row??check my edited answer.

Comment: yes @Pratik I want add 4 views in one raw,,each view use the same xml file to layout it-self

Comment: @Moe see my edited answer and also 1 thing fixed the width of row.xml i mean put TextView and ImageView in 1 LinearLayout and give the width of LinearLayout wrap_content otherwise you cannot see other views.

Comment: I tried this @Pratik but it's dont appears... I think it works by making the LinearLayout a class like this: 

class myRowItem extends LinearLayout{.....} and I can add this myRowItem many times by creating a new myRowItem evry loop iterator

tableRow.addView(new myRowItem(this));

thank you alot Pratik :)

Comment: @Moe anyways u can also add like u have mentioned in above comment.I m wonder why my code is not working..!!